# D-optimal design with nuisance parameters

Tags: experiment-design, multivariate-regression, optimal

I am a mechanical engineer trying to develope an optimal design of experiments in a problem with nuisance parameters. I would like to calculate the parameters $\mathbf{d}$ to optimally estimate parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}_1$ from measurements $\mathbf{y}_m$. My main doubts are related to how to determine the Fisher information matrix of such a problem. In the following I describe the problem precisely:

$\textbf{The problem}$

Let us consider a model very similar to that of Equation (1) in paper [1]. Let ${\mathbf{A}}_1({\mathbf{d}})$ and ${\mathbf{A}}_2({\mathbf{d}})$ be two matrices that are non-linear functions of a design parameters vector ${\mathbf{d}}$. Let ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1\in \mathbb{R}^v$ and ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2\in \mathbb{R}^w$ be two vectors of parameters (in paper [1] it is supposed that $v=w$) being ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2$ the nuisance parameters vector. We are not interested in estimating them but they are present in the model. Let ${\mathbf{y}}_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an observable random vector. It represents the outputs of $n$ different variables.

The linear model that relates the variables can be written as:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{y}}_m = {\mathbf{y}} +{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} = {\mathbf{A}}_1({\mathbf{d}}){\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 + {\mathbf{A}}_2({\mathbf{d}}){\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2 + {\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1)
%    \label{eq::model}
\end{equation}
where ${\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a random vector whose expectation is $E[{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}]={\mathbf{0}}$, its covariance matrix is $E[{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}']=\sigma_\epsilon^2{\mathbf{I}}_n$, ${\mathbf{I}}_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ is the variance of a single element of ${\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}$. It can be supposed that ${\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \sim \mathcal{N}({\mathbf{0}},\sigma_\epsilon^2{\mathbf{I}}_n)$ if necessary.

The objective is twofold:

- Determine the values of vector ${\mathbf{d}}$ that minimize the D-optimality criterion based on Fisher Information Matrix (FIM).
- Determine the BLUE of ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$.

$\textbf{The questions}$

The main doubt I have is related to the expression of the FIM. I have seen different definitions of the FIM for linear models but I do not know if those can be applied to a problem with nuisance parameters.

Moreover, in paper [1] an expression for the FIM is provided (for a similar problem) but it depends on $\textit{a}$ generalized inverse of a matrix. But how can I decide which of the infinite number of generalized inverses should I use?

Another way of expressing these doubts are the next questions:

- In paper [1] (between Equations (2) and (3)) matrix ${\mathbf{X}}^-$ is defined as $\textit{a}$ generalized inverse of matrix (GIM) of ${\mathbf{X}}$. As an infinite number of GIM-s can exist, can ${\mathbf{X}}^-$ be any GIM, or does it have to be an specific one? For example $\textit{the}$ Penrose-Moore generalized inverse.
- As the FIM depends on a GIM, should ${\mathbf{X}}^-$ be the GIM that minimizes the D-optimality criterion based on FIM?
- If the answer to the previus question is affirmative, is there any way of parametrizing all the possible GIM-s of a matrix to apply any numerical algorithm to obtain the optimum ${\mathbf{d}}$ and the related Best Linear Unbiased Estimator (BLUE)?

$\textbf{First approach}$

My first approach without knowing anything of the peculiarities of the problems with nuisance parameters is the next:

For the model of Eq.(1) let us find a matrix ${\mathbf{H}}$ of dimensiones $v\times n$, so that:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_1={\mathbf{I}}_v, \qquad {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_2={\mathbf{0}}_{v\times w}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2)
%    \label{eq::constraints}
\end{equation}
As a consequence:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{y}}_m={\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_1{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 + {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_2{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2 +{\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} = {\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 + {\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}
\end{equation}
and therefore we can propose the next unbiased estimator for ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$:
\begin{equation}
     \hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1 = {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{y}}_m
\end{equation}

Let us calculate the covariance matrix of ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$. First we calculate $\hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$:
\begin{equation}
    \hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{y}}_m-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\mathbf{H}}({\mathbf{A}}_1{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1+{\mathbf{A}}_2{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2+{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}})-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1+{\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}
\end{equation}
The covariance matrix, therefore is $cov({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)$:
\begin{equation}
    cov({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)=E[(\hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)(\hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)']=E[{\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}'{\mathbf{H}}']={\mathbf{H}} E[{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}']{\mathbf{H}}'=\sigma_\epsilon^2{\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{H}}'
\end{equation}

Let us suppose ($\textbf{this might be wrong}$) that the FIM equals the inverse of the Covariance matrix of ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$, i.e.:
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{I}({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1) ) = (cov({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1))^{-1}=\left(\sigma_\epsilon^2{\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{H}}'\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}

Rearranging Eq. (2) one gets the following contraints for ${\mathbf{H}}$:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        {\mathbf{A}}_1'\\ {\mathbf{A}}_2'
    \end{bmatrix} {\mathbf{H}}' = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        {\mathbf{I}}_v \\ {\mathbf{0}}_{w\times v}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \Longrightarrow {\mathbf{B}}{\mathbf{H}}'={\mathbf{C}}
\end{equation}
where ${\mathbf{B}}$ is a ${(v+w)\times n}$ matrix and ${\mathbf{C}}$ is $(v+w)\times v$.

A D-optimal design of experiments (optimal parameters ${\mathbf{d}}$) and an optimal linear estimator (determine ${\mathbf{H}}$ to use estimator $\hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1={\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{y}}_m$) could be obtained as the solution of the following minimization process:

\begin{equation}
    ({\mathbf{H}}^*,{\mathbf{d}}^*)=\arg\min_{{\mathbf{H}},{\mathbf{d}}} -\log\left(\det\left(\left(\sigma_\epsilon^2{\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{H}}'\right)^{-1}\right)\right)\, \text{ subject to } {\mathbf{B}}({\mathbf{d}}){\mathbf{H}}'={\mathbf{C}}
\end{equation}

Is there anything wrong in this approach?

$\textbf{Second approach}$

This approach is different from the previous one because the FIM is defined differently.

As written in section 3.9 of reference [2], if the variance of ${\mathbf{y}}_m$ does not depend on ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$, the FIM can be written as ($\textbf{this might not be the case for a problem with nuisance parameters}$):
\begin{equation}
      \mathcal{I}({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1) =\left(\frac{\partial {\mathbf{y}}}{\partial {\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1}\right)'\left(\sigma_\epsilon^2{\mathbf{I}}_n\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial {\mathbf{y}}}{\partial {\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1}\right)
                  =\frac{1}{\sigma_\epsilon^2}\left(\frac{\partial {\mathbf{y}}}{\partial {\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1}\right)'\left(\frac{\partial {\mathbf{y}}}{\partial {\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1}\right)
                  =\frac{1}{\sigma_\epsilon^2}{\mathbf{A}}_1({\mathbf{d}})'{\mathbf{A}}_1({\mathbf{d}})
\end{equation}

The D-optimality criterion can be written as:
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F}({\mathbf{d}})=-\log\left(\det(\mathcal{I}({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1))\right)=-\log\left(\det(\frac{1}{\sigma_\epsilon^2}{\mathbf{A}}_1({\mathbf{d}})'{\mathbf{A}}_1({\mathbf{d}}))\right)
\end{equation}
and the optimum design determined by ${\mathbf{d}}^*$ would be the one to solve the next minimization problem:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{d}}^*=\arg\min_{{\mathbf{d}}}\mathcal{F}({\mathbf{d}})
\end{equation}

Once the design is fixed, it would be sufficient to find a matrix ${\mathbf{H}}$ of dimensions $v\times n$, so that:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_1={\mathbf{I}}_v, \qquad {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_2={\mathbf{0}}_{v\times w}
    \label{eq::constraints_2}
\end{equation}
and this way:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{y}}_m={\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_1{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 + {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{A}}_2{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2 +{\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} = {\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 + {\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \Longrightarrow \hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1 = {\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{y}}_m
\end{equation}

In order to find ${\mathbf{H}}$, we could rearrange Eq.(2) as:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        {\mathbf{A}}_1'\\ {\mathbf{A}}_2'
    \end{bmatrix} {\mathbf{H}}' = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        {\mathbf{I}}_v \\ {\mathbf{0}}_{w\times v}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \Longrightarrow {\mathbf{B}}{\mathbf{H}}'={\mathbf{C}}
\end{equation}
where ${\mathbf{B}}$ is a ${(v+w)\times n}$ matrix and ${\mathbf{C}}$ is $(v+w)\times v$.

If $n>v+w$ and $rank({\mathbf{B}})=v+w$, there exist an infinite number of ${\mathbf{H}}$ matrices that solve the linear system. A criterion could be to calculate the covariance matrix of ${\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$.
First we calculate $\hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1$:
\begin{equation}
    \hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{y}}_m-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\mathbf{H}}({\mathbf{A}}_1{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1+{\mathbf{A}}_2{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2+{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}})-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1-{\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}+{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1={\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}
\end{equation}
and then the covariance matrix $cov({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)$:
\begin{equation}
    cov({\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)=E[(\hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)(\hat{{\boldsymbol{\beta}}}_1-{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1)']=E[{\mathbf{H}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}'{\mathbf{H}}']={\mathbf{H}} E[{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}']{\mathbf{H}}'=\frac{1}{\sigma_\epsilon^2}{\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{H}}'
\end{equation}

Finally, ${\mathbf{H}}$ could be selected as the one that solves the next minimization problem:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{H}}^*=\arg\min_{{\mathbf{H}}} -\log\left(\det\left(\sigma_\epsilon^2\left({\mathbf{H}}{\mathbf{H}}'\right)^{-1}\right)\right)\, \text{ subject to } {\mathbf{B}}{\mathbf{H}}'={\mathbf{C}}
\end{equation}
for the previously determined ${\mathbf{d}}^*$.

$\textbf{References}$

[1] $\textit{Optimal designs under a multivariate linear model with additional nuisance parameters}$, Katarzyna Filipiak, Augustyn Markiewicz, Anna Szczepańska.

[2] $\textit{Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing: Estimation Theory}$, Steven M. Kay.